# Why does my backtick key not work on OS X?

Tags: macos, keyboard, backticks

On my MacBook (13 inch aluminum late 2008) the backtick key (<kbd>`</kbd>) does not work by itself. In order to insert a backtick, I have to press <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>.

The tilde (<kbd>~</kbd>) works fine.

I'm using the default US keyboard layout. Any ideas why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Check your language settings. While the keyboard may be correct, your regional settings may be the problem.

Comment: I checked them and they all seem correct. But the problem persists.

Comment: What Mac OS X version are you using? Did you upgrade or reinstall you system?

Comment: I did do a clean reinstall a while ago because I messed up my system (Installed GRUB on it, human error). And I am running 10.6.4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to `System Preferences > Language & Text > Input Sources`. There, check `Show Input menu in menu bar`, and make sure the first item in the list - `Keyboard & Character Viewer` is also checked.

Now you can open the `Keyboard Viewer` from the new icon in the menu bar. Green keys are "dead keys" (i.e. they modify the next character you input, like `´ + e = é`). Press shift and/or alt to view the characters you enter while pressing those modifier keys.

I assume that the ` key is -- without modifiers -- displayed in green. If not, try changing your layout temporarily, maybe it will snap back.

Otherwise, check a few other applicable `Input Sources` in the same system preferences pane (British, US, US Extended and US International PC all match your printed keyboard layout except #/£) and switch between them in the list for the new menu bar item. The Keyboard Viewer will update immediately, so you can look for a layout you like, in terms of dead keys and even characters you type while pressing alt (those not printed on the keyboard).

(I have an international english keyboard, so I don't have first-hand experience with your layout)

Comment: Thanks, but when I have the keyboard viewer active, the backtic key isn't green. None of them are.

Comment: Just after posting that, I changed to a US International layout, with backtic as a 'dead key' It seems to be working now. Even though I have to press space to terminate it. Thanks!